# On Soundararajan's explicit formula

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

I'm reading Soundararajan's https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.0723.pdf, and on page 5, one has

$$\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^z} \log (x/n) = -\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(z)\log x - \Big(\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(z) \Big)' -\sum_{\rho} \frac{x^{\rho-z}}{(\rho-z)^2} + O(1/T),$$
where $\Lambda$ denotes the von Mangoldt function, $\zeta$ the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(\rho)=0, \Re(z) \in (1/2, 2], x\geq 2$ and $|\Im(\rho)|\leq T$. Maybe i'm missing something, but doesn't the right hand side of the above formula have a pole at $z=1$, which would render the formula meaningless at $z=1$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The formula you quote is on page 8 (not page 5). The sum is over all zeros $\rho$, not just those with $|\Im(\rho)|\leq T$. On the other hand, there is the assumption $\Im(z)\in[T,2T]$.

Comment: @user164760: As you move $z$ close to $1$, you also need to move $T$ close to $0$, since the formula is proved under the assumption $\Im(z)\in[T,2T]$. So, yes, the sum of the terms involving $z$ blows up, but so does $O(1/T)$ as well. The two blowups cancel each other.

Comment: I see...$z$ must not be a real number. Thanks.

Comment: On page 8 Soundrarajan also unconditionally has $$\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^{\sigma+it}\log n}\log(x/n) = (\log x)\log \zeta(\sigma + it) + \frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(\sigma+it) + F (\rho)$$ for $\sigma>1/2$, where $F(\rho)=O(1)$ is a sum over the zeros of zeta. Doesn't this entail the RH ?

Comment: @user164760: Soundararajan will know when he proves the Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: most certainly he would...but what am i missing above ?

Comment: Well, he does not say anything like "$F(\rho)=O(1)$. There is a $O(1)$ term on the LHS, but also a sum over $\rho$'s on the RHS, which he bounds by a product involving $F(\sigma+it)$. Now $F(s)$ (defined on page 7) blows up at every $\rho$, so it can easily counteract the blowup of $\zeta'/\zeta$.

Comment: great explanation. Thanks ! I guess it would be fun exploring that formula a little further...

Comment: $F(\sigma+it)$ was defined on page 7. He does not bound $F(\rho)$, because $F(\rho)$ is undefined. You mixup his notation and thoughts with your notation and thoughts. That's rather dangerous. What Sound proves is this: $$\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^{\sigma+it}\log n}\log(x/n) + O(1) = (\log x)\log \zeta(\sigma + it) + \frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(\sigma+it) - \sum_\rho\dots,$$ where $\sum_\rho\dots$ is an explicit sum over the zeros. And, in the next line, he bounds $|\sum_\rho\dots|$ by a product involving $F(\sigma+it)$.

Comment: let $z\neq \rho$. and $\Theta$ be the sup of the real parts of the $\rho$s. We have $$-\int_{\Re(w)=c} \frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(z+w) \frac{x^w}{w^2} \mathrm{d}w = -\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(z)\log x - \Big(\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(z)\Big) - \sum_{\rho} \frac{x^{\rho-z}}{(\rho-z)^2} + O(1/T)$$. ...(to be continued in the next message).

Comment: ...(continuation)...This entails that $| \sum_{\rho} \frac{x^{\rho-z}}{(\rho-z)^2}|=\Omega(x^{\Theta-z-\varepsilon})$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ and infinitely many $x\rightarrow \infty$, else by Mellin inversion we would find that $-\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(z+w)$ must be holomorphic in $\Re(w)>\Theta-z-\epsilon$ for some fixed $\epsilon>0$, contradicting our definition of $\Theta$. So for fixed $z$ with $\Re(z)>1/2$, the left hand side of the expression in the previous message is $O(1)$, whereas the RHS is $\Omega(x^{\Theta -z-\varepsilon})$. Thus we deduce that $\Theta \leq 1/2$.

Comment: @user164760: Sighs.

Comment: @GHromMO, sorry, i will delete my latest comments in a moment, i just thought you or some other person might want to have a quick look...it seems the above argument works.

Comment: @user164760: I can assure you that it does not. Please don't try to prove the RH until you have basic questions like the ones above. Start with small things, and grow them big over a long time.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice. But is your assurance based on belief or fact ? Because i'm yet to see how it fails...

Comment: @user164760: Just write it up, and submit to a journal. You will get a report.

Comment: Sure, but what's your quick opinion ? I would be honoured  and extremely grateful to have it.

Comment: @user164760: I told you my quick opinion. It is wrong. And here I am finished with this topic.

Comment: I mean why are you saying it's wrong ? What/where do you think is the error..?.Surely that's not too hard to say...

Comment: @user164760: You misunderstand the purpose of this site. It is not for discussions, where I say something and then you say something, and we cycle. It is also not for checking proofs, especially of major conjectures. Discuss your proofs with your friends, professors or colleagues, or submit them to journals. That's how these things work.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time (though if you would have pinpointed exactly where the error is, i would have stopped and deleted the RH comments right away).

Comment: Just finished polishing up my argument and submitted the paper to the Mathematics Research Letters. Note that the above argument is not in Soundrarajan's paper, though it was inspired by the explicit formula therein.

Comment: since our RH comments are probably irrelevant for the post, can we delete them ?

Comment: @user164760: Just to explain perhaps why GH wouldn’t “pinpoint the error”: Asking a more experienced mathematician to find problems in your proofs is like asking a plumber to explain how to fix your plumbing. You’re asking them to spend time doing part of their job, for free — so they’ll often be happy to chat for a bit, especially if it’s an interesting topic (which is why MO works well), but if you come back repeatedly, then they will get tired at some point and want to move on. If you keep asking questions as long as they keep answering, then the only way to move on is to stop answering.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, well, i was simply asking for a little favour. Maybe i could email you the full paper and you or your number theory colleague(s) could help me by a quick review ? I don'have anyone around me who can check the argument.

Comment: @user164760: Asking for a favour is fine.  But if you’re asking a stranger, then they’re under no obligation to do the favour if they don’t want to.  And if you keep pushing your request after they politely decline it, then you are soon crossing the line from “simply asking for a favour” to “pestering”.

Comment: Alternatively, one can apply the fact that
$\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(z) = \sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{z-\rho} + O(\log T).$  Plugging this into the expression in previous comments reveals that for any given $\varepsilon > 0$ and real $t \geq 2$, the function
\begin{equation}
F(z)=\sum_{\rho} \Big( \frac{-\log x}{z-\rho} +  \frac{1}{(z-\rho)^2} +  \frac{x^{\rho-z}}{(\rho-z)^2}\Big)
\end{equation} must have a holomorphic continuation at $z=\frac{1}{2} + \varepsilon + it$. This implies that $\Re(\rho) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for each zero $\rho$. But i think we should now delete these RH comments.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, it's really unfair to accuse me of ''pestering'', since i have repeatedly suggested that we should delete the RH comments.